# MSI Laptop wakes up immediately after entering sleep mode

Tags: linux, fedora, sleep, kernel, msi-laptop

Some time ago I posted [on Fedora Discussion](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/laptop-cant-enter-sleep-mode-after-kernel-update) because my Fedora system (MSI Summit e16 flip running Fedora 38) started having problems with sleep mode after a kernel update (actually, starting from kernel 6.3.x and with all later versions).

Unfortunately I didn't receive that many replies there, so I tried to troubleshoot by myself and I found out that **what's causing this problem is probably an internal device of the laptop that is supposed to be used to wake up the laptop from sleep** (like the touchpad or the fingerprint reader? idk) and **that instead is misfunctioning and waking it up immediately after it reached the sleep state**.
I'm saying so because I tried to temporarily disable all the lines in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` using this simple script that I found somewhere online and, after doing that until the next time I reboot, the laptop stays asleep as expected.

So now my question is: **how do I isolate which device is causing the problem? And how can I permanently fix this issue?**
**I suspect that the problematic device could be the fingerprint reader** since it was unsupported up until Fedora 38 and doesn't still work properly since it keeps forgetting the fingerprints I add... is there a way for me to disable it completely and try to see if it fixes the issue?

(I’m not sure about if this is the proper place to ask questions like this, or if I should report this issue somewhere else, since it seems more a kernel issue. Recommendations about better place to ask it are welcomed )

Comment: You could use your method to disable progressively the lines in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` one by one, until the device is found.

Comment: But the file gives me a 4 characters code under the device column... how do I understand which device correspond to which code?

Comment: See [ACPI wakeup 4-letters code meaning?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236127/acpi-wakeup-4-letters-code-meaning)

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop it usually happens because of some devices. I create a pre-post sleep script to fix it.

`/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/fixwake` (it may be in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/fixwake` in your distro):

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    pre)
        echo "Fixing acpi settings."
        true > /tmp/wakeupdevices
        while IFS= read -r line; do
            device=$(echo "${line}" | cut -f1)
            state=$(echo "${line}" | grep -o 'enabled\|disabled')
            echo "device = $device, state = $state"
            if [ "$state" = "enabled" ]; then
                echo "${device}" >> /tmp/wakeupdevices
                echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup
            fi
        done < /proc/acpi/wakeup
        echo "Suspending to RAM."
        ;;
    post)
        echo "Restoring acpi settings."
        while IFS= read -r line; do
            device=${line}
            echo "${device}" > /proc/acpi/wakeup
        done < /tmp/wakeupdevices
        rm -f /tmp/wakeupdevices
        echo "Wake state for devices in /proc/acpi/wakeup restored."
        ;;
esac
```

Then make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/fixwake
```

This script parses `/proc/acpi/wakeup`, finds all devices with `enabled` state and writes them down to a temporary file, then disables them. After wakeup it reenables them back.